# Recreating the columns block - building a custom block

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

As the title, I am looking to recreate the basic functionality of the WP columns block. The reason for this is-

- WP adds a number of controls that I do not want the user to have (variations, width slider)
- The allowed blocks, a column, lets the user add any sort of content they like. I am looking to have control over this with an allowed block list

I have created the following edit function:

```js
( function( wp ) {

    var registerBlockType = wp.blocks.registerBlockType;
    var el = wp.element.createElement;
    var __ = wp.i18n.__;

    const { RadioControl, PanelBody, RangeControl } = wp.components;
    const { useBlockProps, InspectorControls, InnerBlocks } = wp.blockEditor;
    const allowedBlocks = [ 'core/paragraph', 'core/button' ];

    registerBlockType( 'wpboiler-core/columns', {

        apiVersion: 2,
        title: __(
            'Columns',
            'columns'
        ),
        description: __(
            'A block for displaying content in columns',
            'columns'
        ),
        category: 'design',
        icon: 'schedule',
        supports: {
            html: false,
        },
        attributes: {
            columnselect: {
                type: 'number',
                default: 2,
            },
        },

        edit: function(props) {
            const { attributes, setAttributes } = props;
            const { columnselect } = attributes;

            const onChangeColumnRange = value => setAttributes({ columnselect: value });

            let columnsContainer = [];
            for(var n = 1; n <= columnselect; n++) {
                columnsContainer.push(
                    el(
                        'div',
                        null,
                        
                        el(
                            InnerBlocks, {
                                allowedBlocks: allowedBlocks,
                            }
                        )
                    )
                );
            };

            return el(
                'section',
                useBlockProps(attributes),
                
                // INSPECTOR CONTROL BEGIN
                el(
                    InspectorControls,
                    null,

                    el(
                        PanelBody, 
                        {
                            title: "Columns",
                        },

                        el(
                            RangeControl, {
                                min: 2,
                                max: 4,
                                value: columnselect,
                                onChange: onChangeColumnRange,
                            }
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                // INSPECTOR CONTROL END

                el(
                    'div',
                    { className: 'columns__container' },

                    columnsContainer
                        
                ),

            );
        },

        save: function() {
            return null;
        },
    } );
}(
    window.wp
) );
```

The issue I am coming up against is multiple `InnerBlocks`. The function creates a list of InnerBlock areas. However, editing one area changes them all.

I believe one method to get around this would be to create a custom `column` block which contains an `InnerBlock` component, and render that in the `for` loop instead of `InnerBlock`. So something along the lines of...

```js
for(var n = 1; n <= columnselect; n++) {
    columnsContainer.push(
        {RENDER_COLUMN_BLOCK}
    );
};
```

But if I did this, would I still come up with the same issue? That editing one of the columns would in fact edit them all? Does each instance need to have an ID to know which is being edited?

And I am also struggling to find out how I render another custom component inside a block when not using a build-step (es5).

Any help on this task would be appreciated.

#### Update

A 'solution' I have created after coming across the following [post](https://ryanwelcher.com/2020/10/limiting-the-block-count-for-innerblocks/) is as follows, where it basically turns off the block appender once the desired column count is reached. Each new instance creates a custom block called `column` which has its own set of allowed blocks.

```js
// COLUMNS index.js

( function( wp ) {

    var registerBlockType = wp.blocks.registerBlockType;
    var el = wp.element.createElement;
    var __ = wp.i18n.__;

    const { useSelect } = wp.data;
    const { useBlockProps, InnerBlocks } = wp.blockEditor;
    const allowedBlocks = [ 'wpboiler-core/column' ];

    registerBlockType( 'wpboiler/columns', {

        apiVersion: 2,
        title: __(
            'Columns',
            'columns'
        ),
        description: __(
            'Displays content in columns',
            'columns'
        ),
        category: 'design',
        icon: 'schedule',
        supports: {
            html: false,
        },

        edit: function(props) {
            const { attributes, clientId } = props;
            const innerBlockCount = useSelect((select) => select('core/block-editor').getBlock(clientId).innerBlocks);

            return el(
                'section',
                useBlockProps(attributes),
                __( 'Add columns by pressing the + icon. Maximum 4 columns', 'columns' ),

                el(
                    'div',
                    { className: 'columns__container' },

                    innerBlockCount.length > 3 ?
                        el(
                            InnerBlocks, {
                                allowedBlocks: allowedBlocks,
                                renderAppender: false
                            }
                        )
                        :
                        el(
                            InnerBlocks, {
                                allowedBlocks: allowedBlocks,
                            }
                        ),
                )
            );
        },

        save: function() {
            return el(
                'section',
                { className: 'columns' },


                el(
                    'div',
                    { className: 'columns__container' },

                    el(
                        InnerBlocks.Content, {},
                    ),
                ),
            );
        },
    } );
}(
    window.wp
) );
```

```js
// COLUMN - INDIVIDUAL index.js

( function( wp ) {

    var registerBlockType = wp.blocks.registerBlockType;
    var el = wp.element.createElement;
    var __ = wp.i18n.__;

    const { useBlockProps, InnerBlocks } = wp.blockEditor;
    const allowedBlocks = [ 'core/heading', 'core/paragraph', 'core/button', 'core/list' ];

    registerBlockType( 'wpboiler/column', {

        apiVersion: 2,
        title: __(
            'Column',
            'column'
        ),
        description: __(
            'Displays an individual column',
            'column'
        ),
        category: 'widgets',
        icon: 'schedule',
        supports: {
            html: false,
        },
        parent: [ 'wpboiler-core/columns' ],

        edit: function() {
            return el(
                'div',
                useBlockProps(),
                
                el(
                    'div',
                    { className: 'column' },

                    el(
                        InnerBlocks, 
                        {
                            allowedBlocks: allowedBlocks,
                        },
                    ),
                ),
            );
        },

        save: function() {
            return el(
                'div',
                { className: 'column' },

                el(
                    InnerBlocks.Content, {},
                ),
            );
        },
    } );
}(
    window.wp
) );
```

However, doing it this way removes the need for the range control/columns select. But it does act in a similar (although not identical) way to the native columns block.

Again, other suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that you cannot have multiple `<InnerBlocks>` within a single block. Your best option is, as you suggest, to use two blocks: a `columns` wrapper block with a single `<InnerBlocks>` component that can only contain `column` blocks. Each `column` block can then have its own `<InnerBlocks>` component.

You will not need to loop over anything, since the `<InnerBlocks>` component will take care of rendering all the `column` blocks for you. Essentially you will have a `columns` block that outputs:

```js
<InnerBlocks 
  allowedBlocks={ ['my/columns'] }
  orientation="horizontal"
/>
```

Then your `column` block will just output:

```js
<InnerBlocks/>
```

This is exactly how the WordPress core columns block works. I have also successfully used this myself to replace the built-in columns block.

Finally, although it seems like a lot of extra work to add a build step, I highly encourage it. It makes the code significantly easier to read and work with.

Comment: Although it is something I am looking at during a later date, at this time I am not using a build step because of the added maintenance of dependancies. Once I understand a cleaner way to handle the various `node_modules` directories that are installed locally I may begin to switch to it.

Comment: WordPress makes it _very_ easy to manage dependancies. There is only one you need: [`@wordpress/scripts`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/scripts). That will include everything you need to build blocks, plugins, etc. in Gutenberg. Typically you'll have one package.json file per plugin/theme that will include the `@wordpress/scripts` dependency. Running `npm install` from the directory that package.json file is in will install everything for you. Then you just run `npm start` to do your dev and `npm run build` when you want production ready code.